# how to export a page to pdf using dompdf page size to a3 or max width manually

Tags: dompdf

Dompdf how to set auto width or a3 width to pdf exporting using php.

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
                      $dompdf->load_html($out);
                      $dompdf->set_paper('a3', 'landscape');
                      $dompdf->render();

                      $dompdf->stream("ReleaseData.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
```

i am using above script. I am not able to get a3 width of exported pdf. Please let me know how to put more width customized or how to set a3 page width to pdf. i am using Dompdf and core php

Comment: That should be ok. What version of dompdf?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not getting the output when i use a3. the version of dompdf is 5.0

Comment: No output at all? It could be something specific to your HTML/CSS. Sample HTML that exhibits the problem would be helpful. You might also try updating to v0.6.1.